# Не получается вытащить данные

Tags: циклы, 1с

Пытаюсь вытащить данные отсюда - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И при нажатии на кнопку сообщение должно вывести эти данные в сообщение пользователю, делаю так -

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура Сообщение(Команда)

    Для Каждого Данные Из Элементы.ПереченьНоменклатуры.ТекущиеДанные Цикл
        Сообщить(Данные);
    КонецЦикла;

КонецПроцедуры
```

И он мне выдаёт ошибку - итератор для значения не определён

Как это исправить ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Поправил данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришел я значит к решению, не без помощи конечно ))

Оно выглядит так -

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура Сообщение(Команда)
                       
    Для Каждого СтрНом ИЗ Объект.ПереченьНоменклатуры Цикл
        Стр = Строка(СтрНом.Номенклатура) +
            " количество = " + Формат(СтрНом.Количество, "ЧГ=0") +
            " цена = " + Формат(СтрНом.Цена, "ЧГ=0") +
            " суммм = " + Формат(СтрНом.Сумма, "ЧГ=0");
        Сообщить(Стр);
    КонецЦикла;

КонецПроцедуры
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно обращаться к `Объект.ИмяТабличнойЧасти` вместо `Элементы.`

Элементы - это коллекция "контролов" на форме (кнопки, надписи, и т.д.)

Comment: Оу, понятно, но он у меня выводит - ДанныеФормыЭлементКоллекции, как сами данные получить ?